# How to integrate django with existing Postgres database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

To use an existing database in Django, you need to have a model for each table. But creating models for existing tables manually is just too much work. However, there's no need to do that, since Django has a builtin tool to solve this exact problem.

Reference article linked here: [how-to-integrate-django-with-existing-database](https://djangoadventures.com/how-to-integrate-django-with-existing-database/)

Answer (score 8):

Edit settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '<name>',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<host>',
        'PORT': '<port>',
    }
}
```

Generate models for linked existing database tables.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Tweak your tables according to your preferences. Copy all tables and add them to your app models.py

Now create initial migrations for existing tables

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Run the migrate command to apply the migrations, Use --fake-initial option that applies the migrations where it's possible and skips the migrations where the tables are already there:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

At this point, any new changes to the model structure and subsequent migrations would work as if Django managed the database since its inception

Thanks to: **[Dima Knivets](https://djangoadventures.com/how-to-integrate-django-with-existing-database/)**